# Conditional aria label on Angular 10 PrimeNG listbox item

Tags: angular, listbox, accessibility, primeng, wai-aria

I have an Angular 10 [primeng listbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v10-lts/#/listbox) which lists a bunch of package numbers. The packages are in an array like this:

```
fpoPackages = [
    { label: '1Z1320939893893289934', value: '1Z1320939893893289934', damaged: false },
    { label: '1Z1320939893895867489', value: '1Z1320939893895867489', damaged: true }]
```

The primeNg listbox has an options input where you pass are array like this.  The docs also show passing a custom template, which works for me since list items have to look like so, with an icon if damaged and a button to remove the item from the list.

[image]

What I need to do is to have the screen reader read "damaged" for the items that are damaged. You will see below I have added screen-reader-only text that says "package number:" before the label.  This works fine.  That, the label (number) and then the button are all read.  However, any conditional text I try to add based on `package.damaged` does not get read.

In fact, even if I add text to *every* list item at the end, it's not read:

```
<span class="sr-only">Package number:</span> {{ package.label }} is damaged
```

I have also tried this:

```
<span class="sr-only">Package number (damaged):</span> {{ package.label }}
```

but then it doesn't read the number (label).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group packages-list">
  <label id="packageListLabel">Packages</label>
  <p-listbox
    [options]="fpoPackages"
    aria-labelledby="packageListLabel"
    formControlName="packages"
    [styleClass]="'package-listbox'"
    [listStyleClass]="'package-list'"
  >
    <ng-template let-package let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
      <div class="package-list-item">
        <div>
          <span *ngIf="package.damaged"
            ><i class="pbi-icon-mini pbi-alert-circle text-warning"></i>&nbsp;</span
          >
          <span class="sr-only">Package number:</span> {{ package.label }}
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" aria-label="remove package">
            <i class="pbi-icon-mini pbi-close"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-listbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Your bootstrap classes are the problem try removing bootstrap and then check it's working. Remove sr-only class in span.

Comment: Here the example stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-listbox-demo-us16vz?file=src/app/app.component.html